# How to run mocha tests with webpack url-loader?

Tags: node.js, webpack, mocha.js, babeljs

I have the following script:

```
"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack 
--progress 
--profile 
--config scripts/webpack.build.config.js 
--mode production"
```

When I build my project with my config, everything goes well.

```
"test": "cross-env NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:./src NODE_ENV=test 
nyc mocha 
--timeout 30000 
--exit \"./src/**/*.test.js\" 
--require babel-register 
--require babel-polyfill"
```

But when I trying to run `npm run test` i have an error that the file 
which I import cannot be received

> SyntaxError: D:/workspace/messaging-server/src/resources/templates/chat.messages.mustache.template: Unexpected token (1:0) 1 `<table width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">`

Is there a way to run mocha tests in accordance with webpack config?

Answer (score 1):

I was solved problem by this way:

Create new file `babel-ignored.js`

```
require.extensions['.png'] = function () {
  return null;
};
require.extensions['.template'] = function () {
  return null;
};
```

and then i add to script --require babel-ignored.js

```
"test": "cross-env NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:./src NODE_ENV=test 
nyc mocha 
--timeout 30000 
--exit \"./src/**/*.test.js\" 
--require babel-register 
--require babel-polyfill"
--require babel-ignored.js
```

Now, getting any file with `.png` and `.template` extension are ignored by babel-register, that solved my question